# How to design a social network with CosmosDB gremlin API?

Tags: partitioning, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I want to build a social network using CosmosDB Gremlin API, but I'm having trouble understanding how to pick a good partition key.

For simplicity, let's say our application consists only of users, who can follow other users (Instagram style) and Users can create groups that they can place their followers into (Google Plus Circles style).

Let's say the graph database has these vertices:

- AppUser
- FollowerGroup

And has the following relationships:

- AppUser - owns -> FollowerGroup
- AppUser - following -> AppUser
- AppUser - belongsTo -> FollowerGroup

I was thinking the appUserId would be a good candidate for a partition key. That way everything related to that user (posts, pictures, etc.) would be kept in the same partition.

My dilemma is when it comes to following other users. If the partition key is the appUserId, then data for each user will be split out into it's own partition. Which is great for satisfying the rule of spreading writes out across partitions and spreading data evenly.

But what happens when I want to query, say all the people a user is following, as well as get their status. Say i'm following 20 people. The query to get that data would have to cross 20 partitions to retrieve all that data. Which does not follow the rule that queries should pull from the same partition for the most performance.

Can anyone offer me a better partition key to use? Or a better way to model the data?

Comment: Make your PartitionKey something generic like "PartitionKey", or "Key" and have your application set it at insertion time so that you can optimize your different read/write patterns

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem for social network and has been called out multiple times. There are a lot of resources available online to read about this.

- http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/06/scaling-linkedin/
- http://www.adweek.com/digital/apache-giraph-partitioning/
- https://code.facebook.com/posts/274771932683700/large-scale-graph-partitioning-with-apache-giraph/

In essence, it's very hard to avoid queries going cross-partition for a scale-out graph.

The final design choice will really depend on 
1. What scale are you planning to handle 
2. What your query workload (e.g., all queries). If you know all your queries and their frequency you can optimize your partition strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll have to check them out.